# Changed server, now passwords are being hashed in a different way - and old ones no longer work

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm out of my depth here and would really appreciate some help.

Passwords on old server running  PHP  5.2 were stored with $2 at the front of each. Now I'm on a new server running PHP 5.3.10, there's the same 29 characters at the start of each, starting with $2y$10$.

Here's the code on the registration form that deals with hashing passwords - identical before and after server change:

```
function crypto($str){
    $crypto['salt'] =   strtr(bin2hex(base64_encode(sha1('sitename.com'))), '+', '.');
    $crypto['hash'] =   crypt($str, sprintf('$2y$%02d$%s', 10, $crypto['salt']));
    return $crypto;
```

I'm wondering if the solution is as simple as changing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Just a quick question, but has the server changed only or the url/sitename also?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `y$10` is coming from the arguments to `sprintf()`. If that code was on the old server, it should have put that at the front of servers, too.

Comment: Maybe this document is relevant: http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php

Comment: @TheHumbleRat only the server has changed

Answer (score 2):

It might be the rest of the environment that changed too.

Read carefully the crypt documentation (it is not very long):

http://php.net/crypt

Just about all of it is relevant to what you are describing, and would suggest significant OS environment change could change the behavior of crypt. It mentions changes in PHP 5.3.x behavior and dependencies on what hash types are available on the system.

Or it could be this:

> 5.3.0     PHP now contains its own implementation for the MD5 crypt, Standard DES, Extended DES and the Blowfish algorithms and will use
>   that if the system lacks of support for one or more of the algorithms.

So perhaps your old system did not support the algorithm you were using, and now PHP 5.3.x has it built in and all of the sudden using it, making it different.

I suppose the trick would be figuring out the defaults of crypt when algorithms are not available in your old environment, and explicitly setting your code through settings to use that.